# Vue.js, обновление страницы после нажатия кнопки

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js

Есть код на Vue.js, своего рода ToDo list. При нажатии кнопки "X", элемент списка удаляется, а при добавлении "Add", страница перезагружается. Подскажите, в чем причина?

```
<template>
<div class="items">
    <form class="form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add task" v-model="titleItem" @keyup.enter="addItem">
        <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
    </form>
    <div class="menuEdit">
        <nav v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <li> {{ item.text }} </li>
            <button @click="deleteItem(index)">X</button>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
      return {
          titleItem: '',
          idForItem: 3,
          items: [
              {
                  id: 1,
                  text: 'Hello'
              },  
              {
                  id: 2,
                  text: 'World'
              },                
            ]
      } 
    },
    methods:{
        addItem(){
            this.items.push({
                id: this.idForItem,
                text: this.titleItem
            })

            this.titleItem = ''
            this.idForItem++
        },
        deleteItem: function(index){
            this.items.splice(index, 1)
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в button. Если она объявляется в форме, то ей присваивается тип submit.
Решении проблемы заключается в явном задании типа

```
<button type="button">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Присоединяюсь к предыдущему ответу, нужно не допускать явное событие отправки формы. Ещё проще запомнить такую конструкцию - **@submit.prevent**:

```
<form class="form" @submit.prevent="">
   <input
     v-model="titleItem"
     @keyup.enter="addItem"  
     type="text"
     placeholder="Add task"
     name="titleItem"
   />
   <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для предотвращения отправки формы, необходимо отменить действие по умолчанию для события onsubmit. В большинстве случаев достаточно вызвать event.preventDefault() внутри метода обработки.

```
addItem: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.items.push({
        id: this.idForItem,
        text: this.titleItem
    })

    this.titleItem = ''
    this.idForItem++
},
```

Также можно использовать модификатор v-on для предотвращения поведение по умолчанию события:

```
<form class="form" v-on:submit.prevent>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add task" v-model="titleItem" @keyup.enter="addItem">
    <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
</form>
```

Подробнее https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html